# How do I escape a certain character in a variable in a batch file

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I made this script but it doesn't work :

```
for /R %%f in (*.mkv) do (
 ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vf subtitles="%%~nf.mkv" -acodec copy "%%~nf.mp4"
 )

 PAUSE
```

After looking for the problem, I found that the problem is the name of the file, the square brackets have to be escaped (for example `[1080p]coolvid.mp4` should become `\[1080p\]coolvid.mp4`. How can I do that to the name of the file (i.e %%f) ?

Comment: google string manipulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The square brackets have to be escaped

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%f in (*.mkv) do (
  set _a=%%~nf
  set _b=!_a:[=\[!
  set _name=!_b:]=\]!
  set _c=%%f
  set _d=!_c:[=\[!
  set _fullname=!_d:]=\]!
  ffmpeg -i "!_fullname!" -vf subtitles="!_name!.mkv" -acodec copy "!_name!.mp4"
  )
endlocal
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.
- [FFmpeg Documentation: Quoting and escaping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) - Details quoting and escaping specific to `ffmpeg`.

---

**EDIT:**
The original code will fail if you run across a file (or file path) that contains the `!` character because delayed expansion is enabled, and the FOR variable is expanded prior to delayed expansion. So names with `!` will be corrupted.

This is easy to fix by toggling delayed expansion ON and OFF within the loop such that no FOR variables are expanded while delayed expansion is enabled.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%f in (*.mkv) do (
  set _a=%%~nf
  set _c=%%f
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set _b=!_a:[=\[!
  set _name=!_b:]=\]!
  set _d=!_c:[=\[!
  set _fullname=!_d:]=\]!
  ffmpeg -i "!_fullname!" -vf subtitles="!_name!.mkv" -acodec copy "!_name!.mp4"
  endlocal
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: +1, All good, except you failed to mention the limitation of `%%~nf` corrupting file names containing `!` do to delayed expansion. This could be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

Comment: @dbenham Hmm. I'm not sure I follow. Please can you edit and correct the answer so I can learn how to do it correctly? ;)

Comment: Thanks, works great. I had a small problem, it turns out that the -i argument of ffmpeg has to be non escaped (otherwise it says file not found), so I put "%%f" intead of _fullname. The subtitles= argument however must have the [] escaped.

Comment: @mdrlol OK. I don't use `ffmpeg` so I couldn't test it. I wasn't sure whether you needed to escape all the `[]` so I added the code for both ;) I'm happy you got it working!

Comment: @DavidPostill - Your code is not incorrect, it just has an unnecessary limitation. Edit made as requested.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks, That's my learning for today ;)